# English word to describe a person that never follow popular ideas or goods?

Tags: synonyms

There is any english word to describe a person with low profile  that never follow or consume popular ideas or goods?
Or a person with his own lifestyle and his own mind set?

Comment: There are probably any number of words that could apply to this: it is not exactly a novel situation. You need to restrict the question, and provide a minimum of research to show words you considered and then discarded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Informal word for someone who likes to keep to themselves](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311473/informal-word-for-someone-who-likes-to-keep-to-themselves) See also [What do you call a person who is utterly independent and a loner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371152/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-utterly-independent-and-a-loner/371159#371159). Also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104836/how-do-you-describe-this-trait-behaviour/104842#104842).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a single word for a person who doesn't follow the crowd?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303149/whats-a-single-word-for-a-person-who-doesnt-follow-the-crowd)

Answer (score 1):

"nonconformist" is the most apt word I could think of for what you've described in the question.

Other words similar to it are: free spirited, maverick, independent-minded, individualist, etc.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. However bear in mind that "Nonconformist" spelled with a capital N, has a very specific religious sense in Britain, as a collective noun for those protestant denominations which do not conform to the Anglican Church, and the Act of Uniformity of 1662 e.g. Methodists, Baptists, Congregationalists, Presbyterians etc. And this sense may well overwhelm OED sense 2, namely that spelled with a small n, as describing *A person who fails or refuses to conform to a particular practice or course of action.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing me about it and for the upvote.